# Варіант чи варіянт

Tags: різниця-між-словами, граматика, морфологія

Неодноразово зустрічав вживання слова **варіянт** (наприклад, [тут](/a/810/585)), хоча завжди вважав, що правильно писати **варіант**. Електронні словники і google translate при введенні "варіянт" повідомляють:

> Можливо, ви мали на увазі: **варіант**

Тож яка форма є правильною? В чому відмінності, якщо обидві правильні?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Якщо я не помиляюсь, то згідно норми скрипниківського правопису [Чуже і § 62 -](http://r2u.org.ua/node/244) підпункт **б**:

> б) Після всіх пригол. перед голосн. та `й`, при *чім* чуже **ia** передаємо через **ія**, *іе* — через *іє*, *iu* — через *ію* (у загальних іменниках), але *іо* через — *іо*: матерія́л, істо́рія, ко́пія, Азія, соціялі́зм, спеція́льний, мініятю́рний, паліяти́в, амонія́к, діяле́кт і т. ін.; авдіє́нція, гіє́на, кліє́нт, пієте́т, Тріє́ст і т. ін.; трію́мф, тріюмвіра́т, ра́діюс, конси́ліюм, ме́діюм, але Кіу-Сіу і т. ін.; ембріо́н, геліотро́п, біоско́п, соціоло́гія, аксіо́ма, Онта́ріо; крите́рій, ра́дій і т. ін.

Иншомовне [`variant`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/variant) необхідно передавати як `варіянт`.

**Але, зауважу, [скрипниківський правопис](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A3%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81_1928_%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83) не є [чинною нормою](http://litopys.org.ua/pravopys/rozdil3.htm#zvukj).**

Comment: Додам для інформації читачам, що у 1999 році була спроба «відродити» скрипніківський правопис — [проект («проєкт») правопису 1999 року](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Проект_правопису_1999_року) передбачав повернення принаймні частини норм скрипніківського правопису і навіть деяких, що були у вжитку *до* скрипніківського правопису («инший», «инакше», «икати») — але його не прийняли. (Тим не менш деякі люди та засоби масової інформації слідують йому частково або повністю.)

Comment: @Sasha, таким чином сторючи звичайним людям повний _mess_ в голові.

Comment: @BohdanKuts, це Ви зараз про сам правопис 1999 року чи про мій коментар про нього?

Comment: @Sasha, я про те що потрібне щось одне і стандартизоване, на що можна було б рівнятися. Бо одні роблять так, інші притримуються іншого правопису - в результаті виходить _mess_ (я про офіційні і публічні джерела інформації)

Comment: @BohdanKuts, якщо чесно, я навпаки, вважаю, що краще дати людям волю. Тобто якщо одні хочуть писати *А*, а інші — *Б*, — то краще дозволити обидва варіанти. (Правда, офіційний правопис все одно так не робить — наскільки я знаю, «варіянт» не дозволено.)

Comment: @Sasha, людям - можливо. Але я, в першу чергу, кажу про такі ресурси як цей (тобто http://ukrainian.stackexchange.com). Адже тут поширюють, наприкла, слово "инший" яке для мене зараз є відчуженим. Як бути з таким?

Comment: @BohdanKuts, моя позиція така: (1) не треба [брехати](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/q/97/4) у відповідях; (2) відповідно, з цього — якщо питання не стосується безпосередньо якогось альтернативного правопису (наприклад: «як за скрипніківкою треба було б писати „існує“?»), то питання повинне в першу чергу висвітлювати інформацію з позиції чинного правопису (інакше це буде або брехнею, або не відповіддю на питання); (3) але в принципі в самому *тексті* користувачі можуть використовувати те написання, яке хочуть (а інші — можуть їх за це мінусувати/докоряти, якщо хочуть).

Comment: @BohdanKuts, якщо бачите десь відхилення від цього — коментуйте, мінусуйте, обговоройте на [ме́ті](http://meta.ukrainian.stackexchange.com/). Можу створити обговорення на ме́ті з цього приводу, якщо хочете. Крім того, на жаль, я часто бачу, що користувачі часто дивляться з позиції дописувача («о, це наче питання про щось схоже, мені ліньки про це писати, позначу це як дублікат чи поза-темою чи ще що»), а не з позиції абстрактного читача («з відповідей на те питання мені нічого не зрозуміло, бо там трішки про інше, невиразно чи взагалі іншою мовою») — це теж треба виправляти.

Comment: @Sasha, я підтримаю думку Богдана: у приватній розмові (чи навіть листуванні) цілком нормально використання певних діалектів, однак визнання офіційності альтернативних правописів може призвести лише до плутанини та ускладнення мови. Наразі суспільство й так вкрай напружене і роз'єднане, тому поява (старих) нових правописів може призвести до гризні в середині україномовної громади і подальшого її поділу на прихильників та опонентів тієї чи іншої течії. А як бути тим, хто вивчає мову? - окрім значень слів треба буде вивчати декілька варіантів написання/вимови, правил вживання

Answer (score 5):

Фрагмент [інтерв'ю з Ларисою Масенко, Олександром Авраменком та мовознавцем і Тарасом Березою](https://dzerkalo.media/news/proekt-indik-piv-ogirka-yaki-zmini-do-pravopisu-proponuyut-u-mon) щодо правопису 2019:

> — Чи повернули тепер вилучені 1933 року правила? Які зміни запропоновано?
>
> Л. Масенко: — Насправді зміни дуже поверхові. Для прикладу, було б логічно повернути закінчення “-и” в родовому відмінку іменників третьої відміни: радости, сучасности, боли, любови. Зауважу, що закінчення “-і” запровадили 1933 року, та досі у більшості говірок чуємо “и”. Що ж тепер пропонують розробники проекту? Вживати слова з таким закінченням... у художніх текстах. Тобто це не є чітко визначене правило.
>
> Не запропоновано й написання “-ія-” замість “-іа-” всередині слів іншомовного походження: індустріяльний, соціяльний, геніяльний. Не відмінюватимемо й запозичені слова, які закінчуються на “-о” на кшталт: метро — метра, кіно — кіна.  Не ставитимемо апострофа у словах іншомовного походження (перед йотованими після губних): б'юро, б'юджет, п'юпітр.

Правильно ВАРІАНТ.

Answer (score 2):

Граматичний словник з серії "ЦИФРОВЕ ЛЕКСИКОГРАФІЧНЕ НАДБАННЯ УКРАЇНИ", що був розроблений на основі академічних орфографічних словників, каже, що правильно буде "варіант".

[image]

https://www.facebook.com/180689769033511/photos/a.368530956916057.1073741829.180689769033511/498557550580063/?type=3

Comment: Перепрошую, але це вже схоже на спам. Принаймні, інформація про те, де завантажити і як інсталювати ЦЛНУ (Ви не проти, якщо я в коментарях буду так скорочувати?) точно виходить за межі відповіді на запитання «варіант чи варіянт». Якщо питають «які системи/словники Ви знаєте», то це одне (там надати докладну інформацію про Ваш словник/систему доречно), але якщо питають «як пишеться/відмінюється певне слово», то Ви хіба що можете надати інформацію щодо поставленого запитання на основі Вашого словника/системи.

Comment: (Та й те особисто мені трішки під сумнівом, бо не зовсім зрозуміло, звідки бере інформацію Ваш словник: чи дані лише з  ЕСУМ, чи це на основі «Словники Україниon-line», чи це комбінація різних словників — а якщо комбінація різних, то за якими принципами вирішуються випадки незбігу?).

Comment: Будь ласка: (1) **Щонайменше, відредагуйте відповідь так, щоби вона не мала вигляд реклами Вашого словника/системи.** (2) Якщо можете, роз'ясніть, звідки конкретно береться інформація для Вашого словника/системи у цьому конкретно випадку (це зі «Словників України on-line», чи це інше джерело?).

Comment: Первинним джерелом лінгвістичної інформації для граматичного словника української мови в першу чергу слугував академічний орфографічний словник - "Орфографічний словник української мови" С. Головащука, М. Пещак, В. Русанівського, О. Тараненка, створений на основі 4-го видання "Українського правопису" (1993). Далі - це робота кваліфікованих прикладних лінгвістів.

Comment: Дякую, що відредагували.

Comment: «Далі — це робота кваліфікованих прикладних лінгвістів» — яких саме? Тобто Ваш словник є не 100%-ю копією «Орфографічного словника української мови» С. Головащука, М. Пещак, В. Русанівського, О. Тараненка, а Ваші лінгвісти окрім того робили якусь обробку, вносили зміни тощо — то вони, мабуть, мають бути десь зазначені (хай не тут, але десь на сторінці/сайті Вашого словника, бо інакше не зрозуміло, хто відповідає за нього).

Comment: Тобто зрозумійте мене правильно — те, що в даному випадку сучасній нормі відповідає «варіант», а не «варіянт» — це очевидно («варіянт» — це харківський правопис / скрипниківка). Але я хотів би з'ясувати для себе авторитетність Вашого словника загалом. Якщо це оцифровка словника Головащука, Пещак, Русанівського, Тараненка (якого року, до речі), то це одне. Якщо це новий словник (на основі словника Головащука, Пещак, Русанівського, Тараненка, але зі змінами) з **такою-то** редколегією, то це інше. Якщо це новий словник з **невідомою** редколегією, то це третє.

Comment: Перше видання «Орфографічного словника української мови» С. Головащука, М. Пещак, В. Русанівського, О. Тараненка, що вийшов у 1994 році, містить близько 120 тис. слів. Цей словник слугував джерелом для формування основи граматичного словника, а саме словозмінної та акцентуаційної класифікації, для подальшого наповнення словника новою лексикою.

Comment: Наразі граматичний словник серії "ЦИФРОВЕ ЛЕКСИКОГРАФІЧНЕ НАДБАННЯ УКРАЇНИ" містить 261499 реєстрову одиницю, але словозмінна та акцентуаційна класифікації фактично не змінились з моменту їх створення. Створення словозмінної класифікації та упорядкування граматичного словника відбувається у відповідності з чинним правописом 1993 року. Розробники вправі обирати для себе, яким чином вони представлені широкому загалу, іменами чи псевдонімами. Так само, як і користувачі обирають, якому джерелу довіряти. Але є беззаперечний авторитет - діючий правопис :)